# First layout can be a fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, drawable, navigator

I have Navigator Drawer with fragments, but the first layout is main_activity, is posible call fragment just after starting the application.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ScrimInsetsFrameLayout sifl;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private ListView ndList;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sifl = (ScrimInsetsFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrimInsetsFrameLayout);

    //Toolbar

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Menu del Navigation Drawer

    ndList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navdrawerlist);

    final String[] opciones = new String[]{"Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", };

    ArrayAdapter<String> ndMenuAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, opciones);

    ndList.setAdapter(ndMenuAdapter);

    ndList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Fragment3();
                    break;



            }

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

            ndList.setItemChecked(pos, true);

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(opciones[pos]);

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(sifl);
        }
    });

    //Drawer Layout

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


@override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path               // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.arisguimera.calisthenicsroutine/http/host/path      );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path               // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.arisguimera.calisthenicsroutine/http/host/path      );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
 }
}
```

My question is can i call a fragment just after starting the application. I thought something like that, but not work.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Change R.layout.activity_main for my fragment_fragment1 for example

Main_activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



<!-- Contenido de la actividad -->
<include layout="@layout/content_layout" />

<!-- Navigation Drawer Layout -->
<include layout="@layout/navdrawer_layout" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

conten_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">




 <!-- Toolbar -->
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!-- Resto de la interfaz de usuario -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Nav_drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.arisguimera.calisthenicsroutine.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrimInsetsFrameLayout"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:elevation="10dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:insetForeground="#4000"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clogo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navdrawerlist"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</LinearLayout>

</com.arisguimera.calisthenicsroutine.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you add the main_activity.xml code please?

Comment: Well, to view the fragment you would need a FragmentManager, meaning your Activity needs to extend ActivityFragment.

Comment: @Daniel Netzer added!

Comment: @Mohamed Salad I can see all my fragments without extend, cause is I extend my toolbar not work. I just need open first "view" with fragment

Answer (score 2):

Well, to view the fragment you would need a FragmentManager, meaning your Activity needs to extend ActivityFragment. (Im not sure AppCombatActivity does this)  By the looks of the code it seems you know this already.

Ultimately, no you cannot do that because fragments are put on screen by a Fragment class method named **onCreateView**, not **Oncreate**.  Activities are mean't to host fragments, not to inflate fragments straight on.

Answer (score 1):

For a fragment be alive, it should be bound to an activity. Cuz it needs context to inherit some of its usage.

It really depends on what you are understanding as a fragment.

But let me get things straight here: Yes, your first layout can surely be a fragment. But how?!

Your first activity's XML might have a placeholder and your fragment can be inflated within.
Fragments have an method called "replace" which inflates a given fragment into a xml placeholder. You just have to put a R.id for it.

As an example:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I do not get it!

I have this code later, to open every fragment, i have to create too on Oncreate method?

Maybe if more easy if i add my context on main_activity.xml? But information would in all fragments @Tiago Dávila

Comment: @ArisGuimerá you need to replace fragment in oncreate() method on main activity.